# How to search book by id and give output all subchild value using JavaScript from XML file

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to search book by id and give
output of title author year price value 
like

```
search id = 3
```

output:

```
title: XQuery Kick Start<br>
author: James McGovern<br>
author: Per Bothner<br>
author: Kurt Cagle<br>
author: James Linn<br>
author: Vaidyanathan Nagarajan<br>
year: 2003<br>
price: 49.99<br>
```

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
  <book id="1">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book id="2">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book id="3">
    <title lang="un">XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <author>James McGovern</author>
    <author>Per Bothner</author>
    <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
    <author>James Linn</author>
    <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>49.99</price>
  </book>
  <book id="4">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, what have you tried? (We don't write code for you here) I would suggest using the xml2js package.

Comment: i tired but but failed to get output

Comment: Post your code that you tried :) 
Also, the answers here regarding DOMParser are assuming you are using javascript in a web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to convert the String to XML.
After that you [search by the id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) of the book in the xml:

```
xmlDoc.getElementById(id)
```

Then you [search by the tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) inside the book:

```
book.getElementsByTagName(tagName)
```

And all the verification is up to you. Sample:

```js
var text = '<bookstore><book id="1"><title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title><author>Giada De Laurentiis</author><year>2005</year><price>30.00</price></book><book id="2"><title lang="en">Harry Potter</title><author>J K. Rowling</author><year>2005</year><price>29.99</price></book><book id="3"><title lang="un">XQuery Kick Start</title><author>James McGovern</author><author>Per Bothner</author><author>Kurt Cagle</author><author>James Linn</author><author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author><year>2003</year><price>49.99</price></book><book id="4"><title lang="en">Learning XML</title><author>Erik T. Ray</author><year>2003</year><price>39.95</price></book></bookstore>';

parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");

function search(id){
  var book = xmlDoc.getElementById(id);
  
  var title = book.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
  var year = book.getElementsByTagName("year")[0].innerHTML;
  var price = book.getElementsByTagName("price")[0].innerHTML;
  var authorList = book.getElementsByTagName("author");
  var authors = [];
  Array.prototype.slice.call(authorList).forEach(function(val){
    authors.push(val.innerHTML);
  });
  
  
  var obj = {
    id,
    title,
    year,
    price,
    authors,
  }
  
  console.log(obj);
}

search(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse the string and then use `getElementById` and `querySelector`

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString( xml, "application/xml" );
var element = doc.getElementById( "1" );
console.log( element.querySelector( "title" ).innerHTML  );
```

**Demo**

```js
var xml = `<bookstore>
  <book id="1">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book id="2">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book id="3">
    <title lang="un">XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <author>James McGovern</author>
    <author>Per Bothner</author>
    <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
    <author>James Linn</author>
    <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>49.99</price>
  </book>
  <book id="4">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>`;

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString( xml, "application/xml" );
var element = doc.getElementById( "1" );
console.log( element.querySelector( "title" ).innerHTML  );
```